# Trying to figure out a c# linq for the list of objects which can be tagged with multiple categories. Get the category with the associated objects

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

| list of entities | tagged categories |
| --- | --- |
| entity1 | (cat1, cat2, cat3) |
| entity2 | (cat2, cat4, cat5) |
| entity3 | (cat1, cat3, cat5) |
| entity4 | (cat2, cat3) |
| entity5 | (cat1, cat4, cat5) |

```
Class Entity
{           
  Entity Name;
  List<Category> Categories 
}
 
var listentities= somemethod(); //returns List<Entity>  <br>
```

expected output:

| --- | --- |
| --- | --- |
| cat1 | entity1, entity3,entity5 |
| cat2 | entity2,entity4 |
| cat3 | entity1,entity3,entity4 |

Note: I got the desired output using 2 foreach loops and dictionary but want to do it using linq.

Comment: Can you define the classes for input?

Comment: "want to do it using linq". Why?

Comment: I found it tough with lambda or linq so asking if someone can help.

Comment: My question is so we can understand the rationale behind using LINQ. Is this a homework that requires you to use LINQ? If you can solve it with 2 `foreach` loop, it seems reasonable. I don't think it's possible to solve it better with LINQ.

Comment: Actually in my project most of the list filtering done using linq or lambda. Thanks for confirming that 2 for each is ok to use.

Comment: Please note that I said it's "reasonable" as in it probably can be more optimized though I highly doubt it can be optimized with LINQ. A HashSet _may_ improve the performance for larger dataset but IMHO LINQ is not something you look to if you want to improve performance.

Comment: Your expected output doesn't seem correct. For example, entity1 is tagged with cat2 so entity1 should be in the list for cat2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined an `Entity` class as

```csharp
public class Entity(string name, List<string> categories)
{
    public string Name { get; } = name;

    public List<string> Categories { get; } = categories;
}
```

If a category is a custom type, it may need to be equatable.

I defined a test `SomeMethod` method as

```csharp
static List<Entity> SomeMethod()
{
    return new List<Entity>{
        new Entity("Ent 1", new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", }),
        new Entity("Ent 2", new List<string> { "2", "4", "5", }),
        new Entity("Ent 3", new List<string> { "1", "3", "5", }),
        new Entity("Ent 4", new List<string> { "2", "3", }),
        new Entity("Ent 5", new List<string> { "1", "4", "5", }),
    };
}
```

### Double Loop - No Linq

First, an approach that doesn't use Linq.

```csharp
var listEntities = SomeMethod();
var dict = new Dictionary<string, IList<Entity>>();
foreach (var entity in listEntities)
{
    foreach (var category in entity.Categories)
    {
        if (!dict.TryGetValue(category, out var value))
        {
            value = new List<Entity>();
            dict.Add(category, value);
        }

        value.Add(entity);
    }
}

foreach (var key in dict.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{key}: {string.Join(", ", dict[key].Select(e => e.Name))}");
}
```

Basically, loop over the list of `Entity` objects and loop over the categories within an `Entity` object to fill a Dictionary.

### Linq

This time using Linq.

```csharp
var listEntities = SomeMethod();
var groupByCategory =
    listEntities.SelectMany(e => e.Categories.Select(c => new { Category = c, Entity = e, }))
        .GroupBy(ce => ce.Category, (cat, ents) => new { Category = cat, Entities = ents });

foreach (var group in groupByCategory)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{group.Category}: {string.Join(", ", group.Entities.Select(e => e.Entity.Name))}");
}
```

The return of `GroupBy` is roughly equivalent to the dictionary and it can be 'cleaned up' a bit by supplying a `resultSelector`.

Both approaches produce the following output:

```plaintext
1: Ent 1, Ent 3, Ent 5
2: Ent 1, Ent 2, Ent 4
3: Ent 1, Ent 3, Ent 4
4: Ent 2, Ent 5
5: Ent 2, Ent 3, Ent 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
listentities
    .SelectMany(e => e.Categories.Select(c => new {
        Entity = e,
        Category = c
     })
    .GroupBy(ec => ec.Category)
    .Select(g => new {
        Category = g.Key,
        Entities = g.Select(ec => ec.Entity).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

This expands the Entities data into {Entity, Category} pairs, groups by Category and then builds out the result.

The final results can be adjusted to just include names instead of object references, if that is desired. Also, entity names can be joined into a singe string using `.Aggregate()` or `String.Join()` if that is what you want.

*Not sure about `.GroupBy(ec => ec.Category)`. If Category is not `IEquatable`, you may need to `.GroupBy(ec => ec.Category.Name)`, in which case the later `Category = g.Key` would need to change to `Category = g.First().Category`.*

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, you can use `SelectMany` and `Distinct` to get what you want though as my comment said, it's probably not faster than what you already did:

```cs
Entity[] entities = [
    new("Ent 1", ["1", "2", "3"]),
    new("Ent 2", ["2", "4", "5"]),
    new("Ent 3", ["1", "3", "5"]),
    new("Ent 4", ["2", "3", ]),
    new("Ent 5", ["1", "4", "5"]),
];

var categories1 = entities
    .SelectMany(q => q.Categories)
    .Distinct()
    .Select(q => new Category(
        q,
        entities
            .Where(w => w.Categories.Contains(q))
            .Select(q => q.Name)
        .ToList()));

foreach (var cat in categories1)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{cat.Name}: {string.Join(", ", cat.Entities)}");
}

public record Entity(string Name, List<string> Categories);
public record Category(string Name, List<string> Entities);
```